# How to add path parameters in httpclient when building rest-api

Tags: java, apache, httpclient, jira-rest-java-api

I have the following uri

www.xyz.com - base uri
I need to add userId to end of the uri as path parameter.

As per swagger document the uri format is www.example.com/{userId}

Parameter type = Path ,Value = userId(String)

I could add body to the post request. However I am not able to add userId as path parameter. I was only able to add the parameter is query parameter but have difficulty in adding it as path parameter.

Code Snippet

```
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
String userId = "25efba57-673b-45ae-9eed-41588730aaaa";
String baseUri = "http://www.example.com";
URIBuilder exampleUri = new URIBuilder(baseUri);
exampleUri.addParameter("userId",userId);
String generatedUri = mandrakeUri.toString();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(generatedUri);
```

Generated URI = https://www.example.com/?userId=25efba57-673b-45ae-9eed-41588730aaaa

Expected URI = https://www.example.com/25efba57-673b-45ae-9eed-41588730aaaa

Please help me to add path parameter in http post. I also tried setparameter method but still not able to add it.

Comment: Can you try this
`URIBuilder exampleUri = new URIBuilder(baseUri+"/"+userId);`

Comment: I am getting the expected url after doing the following
    URIBuilder exampleUri = new URIBuilder(baseUri+"/"+userId);




 https://www.example.com/25efba57-673b-45ae-9eed-41588730aaaa

However I am getting unauthorized 401 because the userId is not getting added as path parameter.

Answer (score 3):

```
String baseUri = "http://www.example.com";    
URIBuilder exampleUri = new URIBuilder(baseUri);
exampleUri.setPath("/" + userId);
String generatedUri = mandrakeUri.toString();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(generatedUri)
```

[Refer the docs here](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIBuilder.html#setPath(java.lang.String))

Comment: I am getting the following error

HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 405 HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL

However I am able to do a post from swagger.

Answer (score 1):

Try concatenating the Strings baseUri and userId.
Also check if baseUri has a slash "/" or add it before concatenating.

Comment: Tried with "/" and without slash but doesnt give me the response it only says post is not support for this url. However same works from mandrake.